# how can I NOT include bootstrap css in shiny UI

Tags: shiny, shinybs

I've got a team who has built plenty with shiny UI (and also shinydashboard) but I'd like to come through and restyle the entire set of apps we've built.

I can link to our css in a number of ways, but that's just setting a new css file on top of the bootstrap base css. ***I have not found a way to just ditch the bootstrap css entirely. Is this possible? *** Even setting theme to NULL seems to still keep that base css in there.

This causes issues of specificity that I have to overcome, which is annoying.

(I realize by ditching bootstrap I will have to recreate many styles they've defined -- and am losing some of the value of shiny, that's not a problem at this point for me)

Answer (score 5):

The `shiny` package includes a function `suppressDependencies` which may be used to drop web dependencies. See `?shiny::suppressDependencies` for more information. Unfortunately, I do not believe one can remove *only* the bootstrap CSS resource, instead one must remove all bootstrap related resources. This appears to be a result of how `shiny` handles resource dependencies, i.e. all the bootstrap related resources are bundled under the name `"bootstrap"` which `suppressDependencies` looks for and then drops entirely.

Limitation aside, I put together a small demo Shiny application showing how to drop the bootstrap resources.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = tagList(
    suppressDependencies("bootstrap"),
    tags$p("Hello, world!")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

  }
)
```

Comment: is there a way to remove bootstrap when we are using `rmarkdown::run` with `runtime: shiny` ?