# How to remove Bootstrap css from rmarkdown::run html_document with shiny runtime

Tags: css, r, shiny, r-markdown

I'm trying to make this simple shiny app using `html_document` and `runtime: shiny`.

Here  is my Rmd:

```
<!-- 
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path))
Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC = "C:/Users/xx/scoop/apps/rstudio/current/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools")
rmarkdown::run("test.Rmd", shiny_args = list(port = 5050, host = "0.0.0.0", launch.browser = F))
 -->

---
title: "xxx"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: null
runtime: shiny
---

test
```

and I run this .Rmd file with

```
rmarkdown::run("test.Rmd", shiny_args = list(port = 5050, host = "0.0.0.0", launch.browser = F))
```

And when I inspect the elements of that page I can see bootstrap.min.css which I would like to remove completely to be able to use only my own:

[image]

I have tried:

- setting `theme: null`
- setting the custom css in yaml `css: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css`
- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528142/how-can-i-not-include-bootstrap-css-in-shiny-ui) only works for shiny apps that have a defined ui
- I looked in all the [rmarkdown::run doc](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/reference/run.html) parameters

Answer (score 0):

Use the `render_args` argument:

```r
rmarkdown::run(
  "test.Rmd", default_file = "test.Rmd", 
  shiny_args = list(
    port = 5050, host = "0.0.0.0", launch.browser = TRUE
  ), 
  render_args = list(
    output_format = rmarkdown::html_document(theme = NULL)
  )
)
```